# Density Estimation In R

Tags: r, kernel-density

I've estimated the density of old faithful using:

```
 library(np)
 library(datasets)
 data(faithful)
 f <- npudens(~eruptions+waiting,data=faithful)
```

How do I find the density of a point not in faithful? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?npudens` says that `npdensity` objects have a `predict` method:

```
predict(f,newdata=data.frame(eruptions=3.5,waiting=70))
## [1] 0.004473444
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find any doc for predict().npudens so I used predict().lm which doesn't mention that newdata has to be a named arg. I'm getting the strong feeling that I have something to learn about finding and reading R doc.